# Position icon at the top right corner of a div

Tags: html, css

I created this code, but I don't able to put the icon on the right corner of div with class valori.

Here the desired result :

[image]

Here the code :

**HTML**

```
<div class="circletop">
<div class="numberpr">3° anno</div>
<div class="lordo">Valore lordo stimato</div>
<!--I add div icon here-->
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="valori"> <?=$min3_anno ." - " . $max3_anno?></div>
</div>
```

Here my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5g42Lx7n/
 I need to add the icon in the top right corner like image.

thanks

Comment: can you link your icon as well in you demo link ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an icon like your showing image, here is the solution

HTML:-

```
<div class="circletop">
  <div class="numberpr">3° anno</div>
  <div class="lordo">Valore lordo stimato</div>
  <!--I add div icon here-->
  <div class="icon">my icon</div>
  <div class="valori"> &euro; 65.000 - &euro; 67.000</div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.circletop {
  /* circle styles */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
      font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ccc;

  /* become a flex container */
  /* its children will be flex items */
  display: flex;
  /* place items in column */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* center flex items horizontally */
  align-items: center;
  /* center all content vertically */
  justify-content: center;
}

/* simulate one more item to "balance" dex text */
.circletop:before {
  content: "\A0";
  visibility: hidden;
}

.lordo {
    color: #45cec8;
           padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 19px;
}

.valori {
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #05c6bf;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px #45cec8;
        font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.icon {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -19px;
    right: -162px;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Check https://jsfiddle.net/bgo2e5zk/4/

```
.icon{position:absolute;right:0;top:-15px}
.valori{position:relative;}
```

I put the icon inside `.valori`, then add `position:relative` to `.valori` and `position:absolute` to `.icon`, and to finish, set `top and left` to the icon to positioning it.

Comment: can you please tell me , why did you add `position:relative` to valori ? i dont know how to use combinatoin of child absolute and parent relative, is there any tutorial to guide about this concept?

Answer (score 1):

Put the icon div inside valori div and set valori to `position:relative` and icon to `position:absolute`. See code below

```css
.circletop {
  /* circle styles */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
      font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ccc;
  
  /* become a flex container */
  /* its children will be flex items */
  display: flex;
  /* place items in column */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* center flex items horizontally */
  align-items: center;
  /* center all content vertically */
  justify-content: center;
}

/* simulate one more item to "balance" dex text */
.circletop:before {
  content: "\A0";
  visibility: hidden;
}

.lordo {
    color: #45cec8;
           padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 19px;
}

.valori {
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #05c6bf;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px #45cec8;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}
.icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circletop">
  <div class="numberpr">3° anno</div>
  <div class="lordo">Valore lordo stimato</div>
  <!--I add div icon here-->
  <div class="valori"><div class="icon"></div> <?=$min3_anno ." - " . $max3_anno?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to position your icon. I have used a dummy icon, you can try using yours and play with the position that suits your need.

```css
.circletop {
  /* circle styles */
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
      font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #ccc;
  
  /* become a flex container */
  /* its children will be flex items */
  display: flex;
  /* place items in column */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* center flex items horizontally */
  align-items: center;
  /* center all content vertically */
  justify-content: center;
}

/* simulate one more item to "balance" dex text */
.circletop:before {
  content: "\A0";
  visibility: hidden;
}

.lordo {
    color: #45cec8;
           padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 19px;
}

.valori {
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #05c6bf;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px #45cec8;
        font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.imageRight {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: -20px;
  right: -10px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="circletop">
  <div class="numberpr">3° anno</div>
  <div class="lordo">Valore lordo stimato</div>
  <!--I add div icon here-->
<div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="valori"> <?=$min3_anno ." - " . $max3_anno?><img class="imageRight" src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/24/000000/checkmark.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.valori {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     }
```

there can be unneeded paddings and margins. If so:

```
.valori {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 0;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     }
```

otherways add this:

```
z-index: 1000;
```